# Test the date format to make sure it has been input correctly

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a test in bash that will check that a date has been entered correctly (or that a date has been entered at all).  Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
tDate=$(lastCOB)
tDateOkay=0

until [ $tDateOkay -eq 1 ] ; do
    read -p "Please Enter date for search.  Use format: Date (YYYYMMDD): " -e -i "$tdate" tDate
        if [[ -z "$tDate" || {check for valid YYMMDD format}]] ; then
                echo "Invalid date. Please enter date in the correct format."
        elif [[ $tDate -gt $(today)|| $tdate -eq $(today) ]] ; then
                echo "Date must be in the past.  Please try again."
        else
            tDateOkay=1
        fi
done
```

The date has to be in the past and has to be written in the correct format, or the data won't be pulled from the correct folder.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# other stuff
elif (( `date +%s -d $tDate` >= `date +%s` ))
then
  echo 'Date must be in the past.  Please try again.'
  # other stuff
```